# Sharepoint Classic Development with React/Angular

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, reactjs

I am tasked with developing an intranet site on Sharepoint Server 2019 for a client. I would love to use Next.JS framework to develop the site. I would like to know if it is possible to use Next.JS framework in the classic experience? I would not like to have everything in a single default.aspx page using a content editor, but have different pages for different routes so that they can be book-marked. After a lot of searching, what I found only is to load all tsx files in an Asset Library and use a content editor web part to display the site. Any advises or links that can explain such scenario would be beneficial. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a modern front end framework, I would consider using the modern SharePoint experience instead. The modern experience is built around modern client side frameworks which would allow you to use React by creating your web parts and extensions using SPFx.

[Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, due to security regulations, we cannot use Sharepoint Online, and Sharepoint Modern experience on Sharepoint 2019 is quite limited in terms of functionalities and the SPFx version is restricted to v1.4.1. This poses a challenge in terms of customization and the support for multi-lingual sites is very bad. Hence we decided to stick to classic design.

Comment: The modern experience is still significantly better than classic SharePoint which is very outdated by this point. There is multilingual support, more information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/plan-for-multilingual-sites